# Using SED to insert line feeds in a file

Tags: regex, sed

I have a dump of all the grizzly-step hosts in a text file.  Here is what the file looks like:

`(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d  (Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d`

As you can see, its one big giant run-on.  I would like to use sed to match `(T` and insert a line  feed before the matched string.  Basically I would like the output to look like this:

```
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d  
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d 
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this:

```
AMD$ sed 's/(T/\n&/g' File

(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89..b.c.d
(Table: network_objects) Name: Bad-Host_89.b.c.d
```

Comment: Perhaps that is a GNU extension - my sed inserts a literal `n`    And I am not the only one - see the last answer at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/sed-insert-a-newline-why-does-not-it-work-158806/